# php, как получить правильный формат даты Y-m-d-THH H:i:s+z

Tags: php

мне нужно получить такой формат даты `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+z   "2017-06-01 13:00:00+0500"`

я пытаюсь использовать для этого `date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+z')`

но мне возвращает `2021-07-26T12:18:08+206`

как получить правильный формат данных? На сколько я понимаю +206 это какое то будущее или еще что то

Comment: всё есть здесь, https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php - и что такое z, и как получить +0500

Comment: Скорее всего последние 4 цифры это "Разница с временем по Гринвичу без двоеточия между часами и минутами".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

206 это порядковый номер дня в году. Нужно использовать O

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:sO')
```

Comment: код неверный, надо исправить

Comment: @Ипатьев надо так надо

Comment: @Эникейщик, ошибка в знаке +. Он будет дублироваться в вашем коде.

Comment: @VenZell да я просто скопировал код из вопроса, заменив одну букву на другую. Ладно, уберу :)